# InvalidArgumentError after step 6 during my training on TPU at Kaggle

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kaggle, tpu

I am getting an error when I train my model with TPU on kaggle. I already looked around the internet but can get any solution. Note that it is working if I use GPU but I run OOM error.

Here is the parameter:

```
batch_size = 8 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
tensorflow v 2.4.1
TPU v3-8
```

Here is my code

```py
try: # detect TPUs
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver.connect() # TPU detection
    strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)
except ValueError: # detect GPUs
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() # for GPU or multi-GPU machinesof multi-GPU machines

image_shape =(224, 224,3)
batch_size = 8 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
N_epoch = 200 # number of epoches

# I created the model using the strategy
with strategy.scope():
    model = ... # I create the model here

def train_step(in_one, in_two):
    loss_ = model.train_on_batch([in_one,], [in_two,])
    return loss_

for epoch in range(N_epoch):
    for step, (in_one, in_two) in enumerate(zip(data_one, data_two)):
        loss_ = train_step(in_one, in_two)
        if step % 1 == 0:
            print("epoch> %d | step> %d | loss>%.2f" % (epoch+1,step, loss_))
```

The training process is working fine till it's reach the step 6.

Here is the output of my training with the error

```
epoch> 1 | step> 0 | loss>0.09
epoch> 1 | step> 1 | loss>0.08
epoch> 1 | step> 2 | loss>0.07
epoch> 1 | step> 3 | loss>0.07
epoch> 1 | step> 4 | loss>0.07
epoch> 1 | step> 5 | loss>0.08
epoch> 1 | step> 6 | loss>0.07
2022-12-16 06:28:40.938812: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/remote_tensor_handle_data.cc:76] Unable to destroy remote tensor handles. If you are running a tf.function, it usually indicates some op in the graph gets an error: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_63]]
  (1) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_95]]
  (2) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_111]]
  (3) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_47]]
  (4) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_35854588329 ... [truncated]
2022-12-16 06:28:40.940134: W ./tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/destroy_tensor_handle_node.h:57] Ignoring an error encountered when deleting remote tensors handles: Invalid argument: Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 17806, Output num: 0
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:worker/replica:0/task:0:
:{"created":"@1671172120.940038755","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:10.0.0.2:8470","file":"external/com_github_grpc_grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 17806, Output num: 0","grpc_status":3}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20/2809624530.py in <module>
     11     # Train the discriminator & generator on one batch of real images.
     12     for step, (low, high) in enumerate(zip(dataL_all, dataH_all)):
---> 13         loss_ = train_step(low, high)
     14         historic.append(loss_)
     15 

/tmp/ipykernel_20/2809624530.py in train_step(low, high)
      1 def train_step(low, high):
----> 2     loss_ = model.train_on_batch([low,], [high,])
      3 #     tensorboard.on_epoch_end(epoch, named_logs(model, loss_))
      4     return loss_
      5 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics, return_dict)
   1729     if reset_metrics:
   1730       self.reset_metrics()
-> 1731     logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   1732     if return_dict:
   1733       return logs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in to_numpy_or_python_type(tensors)
    512     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.
    513 
--> 514   return nest.map_structure(_to_single_numpy_or_python_type, tensors)
    515 
    516 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    657 
    658   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    661 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    657 
    658   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 659       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    660       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    661 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t)
    508   def _to_single_numpy_or_python_type(t):
    509     if isinstance(t, ops.Tensor):
--> 510       x = t.numpy()
    511       return x.item() if np.ndim(x) == 0 else x
    512     return t  # Don't turn ragged or sparse tensors to NumPy.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in numpy(self)
   1069     """
   1070     # TODO(slebedev): Consider avoiding a copy for non-CPU or remote tensors.
-> 1071     maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1072     return maybe_arr.copy() if isinstance(maybe_arr, np.ndarray) else maybe_arr
   1073 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _numpy(self)
   1037       return self._numpy_internal()
   1038     except core._NotOkStatusException as e:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1039       six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1040 
   1041   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_63]]
  (1) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_95]]
  (2) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_111]]
  (3) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5/_47]]
  (4) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_train_function_69334}} Compilation failure: Reshape's input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions, but the constraint is ambiguous and XLA can't infer the output dimension %reshape.7586 = f32[3920,16,384]{2,1,0} reshape(f32[62720,384]{1,0} %transpose.7577), metadata={op_type="Reshape" op_name="model/swin_transformer_block_1/window_attention_1/name1/attn/qkv/Tensordot"}. 
    TPU compilation failed
     [[{{node tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_358545883293887456/_5}}]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_35854588329 ... [truncated]
```

Comment: Reproducible code is required. Try (a) with GPU, reduce batch size to overcome OOM. (b). to get the batch-level loss value, why not use callback and stick to the fit method unless you have to use custom loop?

Comment: (a) For the GPU I have already use **batch _size=64/32/16/8/4/2/1** but still getting OOM. I have too much layer which I need because my model did not performing well if I remove some layer. (b) Yes, I do have custom loop and custom model.

Comment: The error message says `input dynamic dimension is decomposed into multiple output dynamic dimensions`.
Can you make sure that you input pipeline returns Tensors with static (and not dynamic) dimensions?